# Evaluate $\ln[(1+i)^7], \mathrm{Re}[\cos(1+i)]$ and $|e^{3+i\pi/4}|$

Tags: complex-numbers

[image]

I am unable to verify my answers or methods for the 3 parts of this question, any input would be appreciated. I have attached my solutions below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1,3) You haven't taken the quickest paths to the answer, but each step proceed correctly from the one before, and you have arrived at the right answer.

2) you have made a mistake.

You are good up to this point

$\dfrac {e^{i(1+i)} + e^{-i(1+i)}}{2}$  but then you say,

$\dfrac {e^{i^2}+e^{i} + e^{-i} + e^{-i^2}}{2}$ which does not logically follow.
Your next step also incorrectly jumps from the step before.

Lets try this again...

$\dfrac {e^{i(1+i)} + e^{-i(1+i)}}{2}\\\dfrac {e^{i-1} + e^{-i+1}}{2}\\\dfrac {(e^{-1})(e^i) + (e)(e^{-i})}{2}\\\dfrac{(e^{-1})(\cos 1 + i \sin 1) + (e)(\cos 1 - i \sin 1)}{2}$

we only need the real part.
$\dfrac{e^{-1}\cos 1+ e\cos 1}{2} = \cosh1\cos1$

Now, as I said, not the quickest path.  I might have said:

$\cos(i+1) = \cos i \cos 1 - \sin i \sin 1=\cosh 1 \cos 1 - i \sinh 1 \sin 1$

Comment: Thank you, my only remaining question is how you reduced cos(1+i) down to cos(i)cos(1)+sin(i)sin(1) because the formula I'm referencing says:  cos(x+y)=cosxcosy-sinxsiny

Comment: you are correct.  However, the i sinh 1 sin 1 term drops away as we only care about the real part.